# How do I fix "dyld: Library not loaded" when using "wget" on a command line for the Mac?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, wget, macos-big-sur, dylib

I'm using Mac OS Big Sur (v 11.4).  Wehn I try and use "wget" on the command line I get this

```
$ wget http://localhost:8000/user/testuser
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/nettle/lib/libnettle.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/wget
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Even after running "brew install wget" and restarting my machine, I get the above error.  How do I get "wget" to run normally?  This is the path where wget is installed ...

```
$ which wget
/usr/local/bin/wget
```

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, here is the output ...

```
$ brew install homebrew/core/wget
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 6 taps (phinze/cask, homebrew/core, homebrew/cask, homebrew/services, pivotal/tap and ethereum/ethereum).
==> New Formulae
airspyhf              cargo-llvm-lines      cilium-cli            f2                    h2c
basis_universal       cargo-outdated        datree                fst                   vite
bubblewrap            chrpath               esbuild               go@1.16               vue-cli
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 883 formulae.
==> Deleted Formulae
procyon-decompiler
==> New Casks
infra             infra             mimestream        mimestream        sigmaos           sigmaos
==> Updated Casks
Updated 292 casks.
==> Deleted Casks
agfeo-dashboard                                         macintosh-explorer
agfeo-dashboard                                         macintosh-explorer
axe-electrum                                            modulair
axe-electrum                                            modulair
boonzi                                                  noraswitch
boonzi                                                  noraswitch
colormunki-photo                                        obyte
colormunki-photo                                        obyte
dnagedcom                                               playnow
dnagedcom                                               playnow
dragthing                                               plecs-standalone
dragthing                                               plecs-standalone
eaccess                                                 privatus
eaccess                                                 privatus
elpki                                                   pro-fit
elpki                                                   pro-fit
finisher-fluxx                                          qtum
finisher-fluxx                                          qtum
finisher-micro                                          qyooo
finisher-micro                                          qyooo
finisher-neo                                            s3stat-setup
finisher-neo                                            s3stat-setup
flow-e                                                  scrooo
flow-e                                                  scrooo
fluxcenter                                              simplelink-msp432e4-sdk
fluxcenter                                              simplelink-msp432e4-sdk
fm3-edit                                                stageplotpro
fm3-edit                                                stageplotpro
imarisviewer                                            tbs-studio
imarisviewer                                            tbs-studio
instant-articles-builder                                thetube
instant-articles-builder                                thetube
instasizer                                              unity-appletv-support-for-editor
instasizer                                              unity-appletv-support-for-editor
jabt-flow                                               unity-linux-il2cpp-support-for-editor
jabt-flow                                               unity-linux-il2cpp-support-for-editor
jidusm                                                  unity-macos-il2cpp-support-for-editor
jidusm                                                  unity-macos-il2cpp-support-for-editor
lightwright                                             wanna
lightwright                                             wanna
locklizard-safeguard-viewer                             zbuc-imgur
locklizard-safeguard-viewer                             zbuc-imgur

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/manifests/1.1.1l
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/blobs/sha256:ff8b2a965c680b4d9baccd60e799d0989e7dc
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:ff8b2a965c680b4d9baccd60e7
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/wget/manifests/1.21.1_1
Already downloaded: /Users/davea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/44061bb7a2f7bbbbbddd0901da6885f571bb53671d2ef9f3b29faa13cdc50ac7--wget-1.21.1_1.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/wget/blobs/sha256:307217b813330eda365570d7540aa2da69c678b6c4b7
Already downloaded: /Users/davea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2229e2908e6815b9ceac4ac5af316c49215750a1c6d0bdc10b3946b273ee648d--wget--1.21.1_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Installing dependencies for wget: openssl@1.1
==> Installing wget dependency: openssl@1.1
==> Pouring openssl@1.1--1.1.1l.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Comment: What happens if you run `export PATH="${PATH/\/usr\/local\/bin:/}"; which wget`?

Comment: That prints out nothing.  Then when I run "wget anything" I get a "-bash: wget: command not found"

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting. `wget` from homebrew-core, the default package repo for Homebrew, doesn't depend on `nettle` at all.

Where did your get `wget` installed from? Uninstall wget and reinstall it back from the default pkg repo.

```sh
brew uninstall -f wget
# tell brew to get wget from homebrew-core explicitly
brew install homebrew/core/wget
```

Comment: Thanks -- included output from running "brew install homebrew/core/wget".  Seems to die with regards to openssl.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you managed to fix this, but I had a similar issue, found fix here: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/3920

```
brew reinstall z3
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases re-installing `wget` will fix the issue. In my case, simply reinstalling `wget` did not resolve the issue. After having tried myriad of approaches, the only thing that worked was re-installing `brew` and then installing `wget`, i.e.:

1. uninstall `brew`:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

2. install `brew`:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```